# Using MEANJS how do I redirect a user after login to return to a secured page they requested?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, meanjs, passport-local

Using a **boilerplate meanjs footprint**, what all do I need to change to modify the following behavior:

if a secured page is accessed eg. #!/item/5123154AFBC456D/edit when the user is NOT logged in, I want to capture this information, then authenticate the user, then redirect them back to their original url.

The closest thing I've seen googling is a guy hooking up events, but the post didn't include the $emits so I don't know exactly where I need to $emit them from, and since the authentication is happening either server side or via the oath callback, I'm just confused.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just flailing looking for inspiration.

I'm just hoping someone else out there has implemented this behavior in meanjs and can help me with guidance on what all I need to do.

Comment: The MEAN stack is built on express. Can't you just use res.redirect()?

Comment: I can't. The angular part is hitting a node REST api, the rest api throws a 401 when the request is unauthorized. The client-side has to do the redirect based on the rest response :\

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: The mechanic of redirection isn't really what I'm looking for. I've never really worked with a client-side authentication scheme before. In my case I would use $state.go() instead of using $route() I think. 

No I'm looking for "you can look at this meanjs project that I had to do this for:". It's very common behavior. I'm just afraid that in this setup it might not be possible. 

Considering using a cookie and then clearing it out post authentication.